# Classic ASP on IIS - Timeout Session not expiring

Tags: session, iis, asp-classic, timeout

I have an classic ASP site on IIS(both IIS 6,and 8) and both perform the same. We've had this issue for years on IIS 5,6,7,8 and never could figure it out. I have a time out setting on the IIS application pool settings of 120 minutes. I do not have a session.timeout setting in any of the ASP code itself. I do have a Session.Abandon in the global.asa file, which works well.

Most of the time if a user is idle for > 120 minutes, it gives them a message that their session has timed out, expires the sessions and redirects them back to the login page.. this is how it should work and most of the time is does.

The issue I have is that about 5% of the time, some users seem to be able to keep the session alive beyond the 120 minutes. Some for days.

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas what could cause this? Some ideas that I think could cause this??

1. I assume they keep their browsers open for days, but could a user that has a browser window open but sitting idle AND on another TAB of that same browser be active on other websites? Does that activity make the TAB with my application still active/not idle? I've tested this on several environments but not able to replicate.
2. Some type of software like a URL filter, proxy server or Antivirus could be causing their browser to not be idle?
3. Of course a user can keep the session idle if they use the app beyond the 2 hours, but it is rather unlikely they do this, especially for days.

Its hard to troubleshoot since the users are all customers. So I have no clue if its a certain browser, browser version, or their network environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried out to set the timeout in the **Application_OnStart** method in global.asa?

I had a similar problem, but in my case the session ended up before timeout. 
After I set up timeout the problem was solved, just including this line:

```
Session.Timeout=20
```

Hope it helps.